# How to upgrade Windows 7 from Home to Ultimate w/o using Anytime Upgrade

Tags: windows-7

My Windows 7 has a bug, VSS doesn't work for some reason. I tried for weeks to fix it without success. Sadly the non-working VSS service means I cannot

- Use Anytime Upgrade
- Upgrade to Windows 10
- Backup or Restore

Cause basically anything tries to create a system restore point before it starts doing it's job. Is there a way to manually upgrade to (preferred cause of old hardware) Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 8.1 or Windows 10?`

Or skip the system restore point check in Anytime Upgrade?

(Why I'm not reinstalling: I got literally tons of software and old hardware running fine on this machine, reinstalling would be a very lengthy process, if it worked at all. As I'm only running legal software, most of my software has activation keys that I have lying around somewhere. It would be a nightmare..)

Comment: There a reason you don't resolve the VSS problem?  What approachs did you use to perform the upgrade to Windows 10.  Be specific

Comment: The reason is simply that all solutions I could find on the web within weeks did not solve the issue.